# R reshape2 dcast: transform data

Tags: r, reshape2, dcast

How can I transform data X to Y as in

```
X = data.frame(
  ID = c(1,1,1,2,2),
  NAME = c("MIKE","MIKE","MIKE","LUCY","LUCY"),
  SEX = c("MALE","MALE","MALE","FEMALE","FEMALE"),
  TEST = c(1,2,3,1,2),
  SCORE = c(70,80,90,65,75)
)

Y = data.frame(
  ID = c(1,2),
  NAME = c("MIKE","LUCY"),
  SEX = c("MALE","FEMALE"),
  TEST_1 =c(70,65),
  TEST_2 =c(80,75),
  TEST_3 =c(90,NA)
)
```

The `dcast` function in `reshape2` seems to work but it can not include other columns in the data like ID, NAME and SEX in the example above.

Assuming all other columns by a ID column are consistent, like Mike can only be a male with ID 1, how can we do it?

Comment: What did you try? This seems to work: `dcast(X, ID + NAME + SEX ~ TEST, value.var = "SCORE")`

Comment: Or use `library(tidyr);spread(X, TEST, SCORE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation (`?reshape2::dcast`), `dcast()` allows for `...` in the formula:

> "..." represents all other variables not used in the formula ...

This is true for both the `reshape2` and the `data.table` packages which both support `dcast()`.

So, you can write:

```
reshape2::dcast(X, ... ~ TEST, value.var = "SCORE")
#  ID NAME    SEX  1  2  3
#1  1 MIKE   MALE 70 80 90
#2  2 LUCY FEMALE 65 75 NA
```

However, if the OP insists that the column names should be `TEST_1`, `TEST_2`, etc., the `TEST` column needs to be modified before reshaping. Here, `data.table` is used:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(X)[, TEST := paste0("TEST_", TEST)], ... ~ TEST, value.var = "SCORE")
#   ID NAME    SEX TEST_1 TEST_2 TEST_3
#1:  1 MIKE   MALE     70     80     90
#2:  2 LUCY FEMALE     65     75     NA
```

which is in line with the expected answer given as data.frame `Y`.